# Glassfish 4.1 Hibernate 5 Error - This web container has not yet been started

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I'm getting an exception with Hibernate when trying to load a class with a Map of .

it works without, but when I add this field to the class it gives the error in the title.

Here are the classes, Person, PhoneNumber, PersonServiceImpl and IPersonService.

All of this seems to work without the Person.PhoneNumber field.

Any ideas?

My test case works fine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getIterations(); i++) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            Person person = getPersonForIteration(i);
            entityManager.persist(person);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            Person foundPerson = entityManager.find(Person.class,
                                                              person.getId());
            doAssertsForFoundPerson(foundPerson, person);
        }
```

Entity and service classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ent_person")
public class Person implements Serializable, Comparable<Person> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    /**
     * Comment for <code>serialVersionUID</code>
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4680156785318108346L;

    protected String firstName;

    protected String nickname;

    protected String lastName;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    protected List<String> middleNames;

    protected String idNum;

    protected char isMale;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)
    protected Date birthday;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "value")
    protected Map<String, PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName
     * @param nickname
     * @param lastName
     * @param middleNames
     * @param idNum
     * @param isMale
     * @param birthday
     */
    public Person(String firstName, String nickname, String lastName, List<String> middleNames,
            String idNum, char isMale, Date birthday) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleNames = middleNames;
        this.idNum = idNum;
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String numberType, PhoneNumber number) {
        if (phoneNumbers == null) {
            phoneNumbers = new HashMap<String, PhoneNumber>();
        }
        phoneNumbers.put(numberType, number);
    }

    public Map<String, PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the firstName.
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param firstName The firstName to set.
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the nickname.
     */
    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @param nickname The nickname to set.
     */
    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the lastName.
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName The lastName to set.
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void addMiddleName(String middleName) {
        if (middleNames == null) {
            middleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        if (!middleNames.contains(middleName)) {
            middleNames.add(middleName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the middleNames.
     */
    public List<String> getMiddleNames() {
        return middleNames;
    }

    /**
     * @param middleNames The middleNames to set.
     */
    public void setMiddleNames(List<String> middleNames) {
        this.middleNames = middleNames;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the idNum.
     */
    public String getIdNum() {
        return idNum;
    }

    /**
     * @param idNum The idNum to set.
     */
    public void setIdNum(String idNum) {
        this.idNum = idNum;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the isMale.
     */
    public char getIsMale() {
        return isMale;
    }

    /**
     * @param isMale The isMale to set.
     */
    public void setIsMale(char isMale) {
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isMale() {
        return isMale == 'y';
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the birthday.
     */
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @param birthday The birthday to set.
     */
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     *
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((birthday == null) ? 0 : birthday.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((idNum == null) ? 0 : idNum.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((middleNames == null) ? 0 : middleNames.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nickname == null) ? 0 : nickname.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param o
     * @return
     *
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        int result = lastName.compareTo(o.getLastName());
        return result == 0 ? firstName.compareTo(o.getLastName()) : result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (this.id != other.id && (this.id == null || !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.firstName == null) ? (other.firstName != null) : !this.firstName.equals(other.firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.nickname == null) ? (other.nickname != null) : !this.nickname.equals(other.nickname)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.lastName == null) ? (other.lastName != null) : !this.lastName.equals(other.lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.middleNames != other.middleNames && (this.middleNames == null || !this.middleNames.equals(other.middleNames))) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.idNum == null) ? (other.idNum != null) : !this.idNum.equals(other.idNum)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.birthday != other.birthday && (this.birthday == null || !this.birthday.equals(other.birthday))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", nickname=" + nickname + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", middleNames=" + middleNames + ", idNum=" + idNum + ", isMale=" + isMale + ", birthday=" + birthday + ", phoneNumbers=" + phoneNumbers + '}';
    }

}

public class PhoneNumber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -423634682785318106L;

    public static transient final String HOME = "Home";

    public static final String PERSONAL_MOBILE = "Personal Mobile";

    public static final String OFFICE = "Office";

    public static final String WORK_MOBILE = "Work Mobile";

    public static final String FAX = "Fax";

    public static final String PAGER = "Pager";

    public static final String TOLL_FREE = "Toll Free";

    public static final String OTHER = "Other";

    String countryCode;

    String areaCode;

    String subscriberNubmer;

    String extension;

    public PhoneNumber() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @param countryCode
     * @param areaCode
     * @param subscriberNubmer
     * @param extension
     */
    public PhoneNumber(String countryCode, String areaCode, String subscriberNubmer,
            String extension) {
        super();
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
        this.subscriberNubmer = subscriberNubmer;
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the countryCode.
     */
    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param countryCode The countryCode to set.
     */
    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the areaCode.
     */
    public String getAreaCode() {
        return areaCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param areaCode The areaCode to set.
     */
    public void setAreaCode(String areaCode) {
        this.areaCode = areaCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the subscriberNubmer.
     */
    public String getSubscriberNubmer() {
        return subscriberNubmer;
    }

    /**
     * @param subscriberNubmer The subscriberNubmer to set.
     */
    public void setSubscriberNubmer(String subscriberNubmer) {
        this.subscriberNubmer = subscriberNubmer;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns the extension.
     */
    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    /**
     * @param extension The extension to set.
     */
    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     *
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PhoneNumber [countryCode=" + countryCode + ", areaCode=" + areaCode
                + ", subscriberNubmer=" + subscriberNubmer + ", extension=" + extension + "]";
    }

    /**
     * @return
     *
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((areaCode == null) ? 0 : areaCode.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((countryCode == null) ? 0 : countryCode.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((extension == null) ? 0 : extension.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((subscriberNubmer == null) ? 0 : subscriberNubmer.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param obj
     * @return
     *
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        PhoneNumber other = (PhoneNumber) obj;
        if (areaCode == null) {
            if (other.areaCode != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!areaCode.equals(other.areaCode)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (countryCode == null) {
            if (other.countryCode != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!countryCode.equals(other.countryCode)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (extension == null) {
            if (other.extension != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!extension.equals(other.extension)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (subscriberNubmer == null) {
            if (other.subscriberNubmer != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!subscriberNubmer.equals(other.subscriberNubmer)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Remote
@Local
public interface IPersonService {
    public Collection<Person> getAllPeople();
    Person getPerson(String idNum);
    public void removePerson(Person p);
}


@Stateless(name = "personService")
public class PersonServiceImpl implements IPersonService {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public Collection<Person> getAllPeople(){
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p");
        return (Collection<Person>)query.getResultList();
    }

    public Person getPerson(String idNum) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName("John");
        p.setLastName("Doe");
        p.setIdNum(idNum);
        p.setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber.HOME, new PhoneNumber());
        em.persist(p);
        return p;
    }

    public void removePerson(Person p) {
        em.remove(p);
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace, too:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[net.somepackage.demo.web.servlet.BasicServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet net.somepackage.demo.web.servlet.BasicServlet threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException
........
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:833)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap.readFrom(PersistentMap.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1922)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:436)
    at net.somepackage.demo.service.PersonServiceImpl.getAllPeople(PersonServiceImpl.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could determine, there was an issue with classloading.  I'm not sure what it was, but when I downgraded to Hibernate 4.3.11.Final things started working properly.

I'm not sure why, and got tired of trying to figure it out.  Once I switched the version of Hibernate everything worked.